# On "menu key" press, ContextMenuStrip does not pop-up at the mouse cursor position

Tags: c#, contextmenu, winforms

In a Windows Forms, .NET 2.0 application, I'm using a ContextMenuStrip control attached to the ContextMenuStrip property of a form. When I right-click the form, the ContextMenuStrip opens at the mouse cursor position.

However, when I press the "menu key" on my keyboard, the ContextMenuStrip does not open at the mouse cursor position, it opens at the same location somewhere in the bottom-right quarter of the form. Is this a standard behavior and why?

How can I write code to change this behavior and make the ContextMenuStrip pop-up at the mouse cursor position when I press the "menu key"?

Answer (score 0):

It is standard behavior.  Try using the key in any other application.  It completely ignores the mouse location.

I would avoid overriding standard behavior.  Keyboard users won't be impressed that all they menus are popping up wherever they last left their mouse.

Comment: Not necessarily. In Visual Studio for example, if something is selected in a tree or the text editor, the context menu key pops up the context menu at this location...

Comment: Yeah, it pops up at the element which is selected, which is still not the mouse location.

Comment: Which is the right thing in my opinion. If you use the keyboard, you get a context menu on the keyboard focused control.

Comment: @jreichert, the question was asking about opening the context menu at the mouse cursor location.  It has nothing to do with the focused control.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's normal behavior. Try pressing the Menu key in this window ;-)